# Unable to connect custom domain to Google App Engine

Tags: domains, google-app-engine, google-cloud

I have successfully completed the steps 1 and 2 as mentioned in the [GAE Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/mapping-custom-domains#adding_a_custom_domain_for_your_application). But unable to proceed with step 3. I have hosted my site on appspot.com but my domain is not yet connected to the application and shows error 404.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of step 2?  What you see after you hit the blue "continue" button from your first screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurred because the domain was already mapped to another project.

I just [deleted](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/domain-mappings/delete) the previous mapping and created a new mapping ans it solved the problem